# Copy and paste into next available row ignoring formatting

Tags: excel

I'm looking to copy information from one page to another into the next available row. The number of rows of data will change between saves. I currently have the following code:

```
Sub CFSNCAll()

    r = 1
    Sheets("CFSNC_All").Range("C12:T298").Copy
    If Sheets("CFSNC_All").Range("C12") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp) _
        Then r = 0
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This works perfectly in an excel sheet with no formatting. My Excel sheet has borders, conditional formatting in two columns in the range, and gridlines turned off. Currently, when you run the macro the second time, the data pastes into the right sheet, but on the 298th row. I think it's registering information in the previous cells from formatting. Is there a way to ignore the formatting and ensure that it pastes below the entry?

Comment: Did you clear your range before running it a second time? If you just pasted 298 values in and then run again, wouldnt you want it to paste right where it is (maybe with an offset of 1)

Comment: Turns out it was counting the empty string ("") which was registering. Added a loop to solve the problem, working well now!